# Problemas con Threads en Pythonanyware

Tags: python, django, servidor, hilos

estoy trabajando en una web usando Django, y en uno de los módulos debo generar reportes, por lo que implemente un sistema asíncrono, donde se pone un rango de fechas, y luego usando trheads creo el reporte en segundo plano, y una vez terminado lo guardo en un modelo, que muestro en un panel.
En mi local funciona de maravilla, pero al subirlo a producción usando pythonanyware, al momento de ejecutar la función que crea el hilo, este se alenta demasiado, al punto que un reporte que en mi local toma 5 segs, en producción puede llevar hasta 10 mins!.
Lo curioso y raro, es que si relodeo mi app, el hilo mágicamente retoma velocidad al punto de finalizar el proceso antes que pythonanyware mate el proceso

[image: Referencia de tiempos]

Aquí el código que uso para la generación de estos reportes:
models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Document(models.Model):
    type_options = (
        ('reporte_con_comentarios', 'reporte_con_comentarios'),
        ('reporte_sin_comentarios', 'reporte_sin_comentarios'),
        ('kardex_multiple', 'kardex_multiple'),
    )
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=type_options)
    date_start = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    date_finish = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    url = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default= False)
```

views.py

```
class GenerateAsyncReportComment(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'reportes/reporte_excel1.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        text = "Se descargará un archivo Excel con las órdenes de servicio con comentarios."
        context['text'] = text
        context['redirect_succes_url'] = 'reportes:async_report_list'
        context['type'] = 'reporte_con_comentarios'
        context['redirect_back_url'] = 'reportes:catalogo_reporte'
        return context
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.POST)
        fecha_inicio = request.POST.get("fecha_inicio")
        fecha_final = request.POST.get("fecha_final")
        fecha_inicio = {'fecha_apertura__gte': fecha_inicio} if fecha_inicio != '' and fecha_inicio != None else {}
        fecha_final = {'fecha_apertura__lte': f'{fecha_final} 23:59:59'} if fecha_final != '' and fecha_final != None else {}
        # generate_excel_con_comentario(fecha_inicio, fecha_final)
        con_comentarios = generate_excel_con_comentarios
        async_generate_excel(con_comentarios, fecha_inicio, fecha_final, kwargs={})
        url = f'%s?type=reporte_con_comentarios' % reverse('reportes:async_report_list')
        return redirect(url)
```

y el functions.py

```
def async_generate_excel(function, fecha_inicio, fecha_final, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=function, args=[fecha_inicio, fecha_final],  kwargs=kwargs)
    thread.start()

def start_document(type, complement_text='Excel'):
    limit_exceles_in_storaged(type)
    date = timezone.now()
    text = f'Se esta generando el {complement_text}'
    excel = reportmodels.Document.objects.create(
        text = text,
        type = type,
        date_start = date
    )
    return excel.id

    
def finsh_document(id, excel, complement_text='Excel'):
    date = timezone.now()
    text = f'Descargar {complement_text}'
    doc = reportmodels.Document.objects.get(id = id)
    doc.text = text
    doc.date_finish = timezone.now()
    doc.url = excel
    doc.complete = True
    doc.save()

def generate_excel_con_comentarios(fecha_inicio:dict, fecha_final:dict, **kwargs):
    id_excel = start_document('reporte_con_comentarios', 'Reporte con comentarios')
    print('Inicio con comentario')
    reportes = {}
    ordenes_servicios = models.OrdenesServicio.objects.filter(
        status = 'cerrado',#Filtro
        **fecha_inicio,
        **fecha_final
    ).order_by('fecha_apertura')

    book = openpyxl.Workbook()
    sheet = book.active
    sheet.append( (
        #Datos del excel, los retiro para ahorrar espacio en la pregunta
        ))
    fuente = Font(bold=True)
    celdas_en_negrita = sheet["A1":"AM1"]
    for row in celdas_en_negrita:
        for cell in row:
            cell.font = fuente
    for orden_servicio in ordenes_servicios:
        print(orden_servicio)
        primer_comentario = orden_servicio.comentarios.first()
        sheet.append( (
            #Datos del excel, los retiro para ahorrar espacio en la pregunta
        ) )
        if primer_comentario != None:
            for comentario in orden_servicio.comentarios.exclude(id = primer_comentario.id):
                sheet.append( (
                    #Datos del excel, los retiro para ahorrar espacio en la pregunta
                    )
                )
        
    sheet.column_dimensions [ 'A' ].width = 32
    sheet.column_dimensions [ 'B' ].width = 20
    sheet.column_dimensions [ 'C' ].width = 20
    bytes_io = BytesIO()
    book.save(bytes_io)
    date = timezone.now()
    archivo_django = File(bytes_io, name=f'Reporte con comentarios {date.date().day}-{date.date().month}-{date.date().year}.xlsx')
    print('Fin con comentario')
    finsh_document(id_excel, archivo_django, 'Reporte con comentarios')
```

Recalco que en mi local así como en la máquina de varios colegas corre perfectamente, y tarda muy poco, el problema recae al momento de ponerlo en produccion, usando como servidor pythonanyware
Espero realmente puedan ayudarme.

De ser relevante adjunto las especificaciones del servidor de pythonanyware
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]